# Ordenar array de objetos com relação entre si - um elemento possui referências ao anterior e ao próximo

Tags: javascript, classificação

Tenho dados provenientes de uma base de dados que são relacionados entre si de modo em que cada campo tem dois outros — um que faz referência ao campo anterior (na tabela) e o outro ao campo seguinte.

Algo mais ou menos assim:

```
... demais campos
id
prev_id
next_id
```

Eu preciso sortear esses objetos que vêm da base de dados de alguma forma. Tentei usar o método `.sort()` do JavaScript, mas não obtive nenhum sucesso:

```js
const positions = [
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 2, prev: 1, next: 3 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 4, prev: 3, next: 4 },
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 1, prev: 1, next: 2 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 3, prev: 2, next: 4 }
];

/**
 * Deve ficar assim:
 * 
 * { name: 'Primeiro', id: 1, prev: 1, next: 2 },
 * { name: 'Segundo', id: 2, prev: 1, next: 3 },
 * { name: 'Terceiro', id: 3, prev: 2, next: 4 },
 * { name: 'Quarto', id: 4, prev: 3, next: 4 }
 */

const newArray = positions.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.prev === b.id) return 1;
  if (a.next === b.id) return -1;
  return 0;
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Eu montei um pequeno exemplo acima usando um *array* inicial e, em um comentário, o *array* que precisa ser alcançado através da ordenação.

---

É importante ressaltar que, como os dados vêm de um banco de dados, **não posso assumir necessariamente que os IDs estarão em ordem**.

Um outro exemplo para ilustrar essa situação:

```
const positions = [
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 3, prev: 1, next: 3 },
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 5, prev: 5, next: 7 },
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 1, prev: 7, next: 3 }
]

// Deve ficar:
const sorted = [
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 5, prev: 5, next: 7 },
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 1, prev: 7, next: 3 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 3, prev: 1, next: 3 }
]
```

---

Um outro adendo é que se o item for o primeiro da lista, ele recebe o seu próprio ID no campo `prev`. Algo similar acontece com o último, que recebe o próprio ID no campo `next`.

Comment: Olá Luiz! Poderia nos dar um feedback? nenhuma das respostas lhe atendeu? Podemos debater e chegar a uma solução que atenda ao seu propósito, se vc quiser. Abs!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não tem como usar `sort` neste caso. Isso porque a função de *callback* usada por `sort` só sabe comparar dois elementos de cada vez. Mas para o seu caso, precisa verificar os outros elementos um a um, até encontrar a posição desejada.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que o array seja:

```js
var positions = [
  { name: 'Quinto', id: 2, prev: 3, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 3, prev: 1, next: 2 },
  { name: 'Sexto', id: 6, prev: 2, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 5, prev: 5, next: 7 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 1, prev: 7, next: 3 }
];
```

Suponha que em determinado momento o *callback* receba o segundo e quinto elementos e tente compará-los para determinar qual deve vir antes na ordenação:

```js
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Quinto', id: 2, prev: 3, next: 6 },
```

Não tem como tirar qualquer conclusão sobre eles, já que nenhum dos id's se repete. No "Segundo", eu sei que o `id` dele é 7, o anterior é o 5 e o próximo é o 1. Mas como eu sei se ele está antes ou depois do outro elemento, cujo `id` é 2, o anterior é 3 e o próximo é 6?

É claro que em alguns casos será óbvio (quando o `next` ou `prev` de um é igual ao `id` do outro), mas como você mesmo já percebeu (e as outras respostas também), isso não é suficiente. Pois no caso acima, se eu usasse algo como:

```js
positions.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.prev === b.id) return 1;
  if (a.next === b.id) return -1;
  return 0;
});
```

Ele retornaria zero, ou seja, **consideraria que o segundo e quinto elementos são iguais** - e como nos *browsers* atuais a ordenação é estável, os elementos considerados iguais ficam na mesma ordem do array original (ou seja, o quinto ficaria antes do segundo).

E como os id's dos elementos não necessariamente refletem a ordem (pelos casos fornecidos entendi que, por exemplo, o elemento cujo `id` é 9 pode vir antes do que tem `id` 1), também não dá para usar os seus valores numéricos como referência.

---

Então a única forma de saber a posição correta de cada elemento é verificando os demais, até encontrar um cujo próximo ou anterior seja o elemento em questão. Aí você saberá que deve vir antes ou depois do elemento encontrado.

Mas como `sort` recebe um *callback* que só sabe comparar dois elementos de cada vez, ele não serve para este caso. Sendo assim, tem que fazer diferente: para cada elemento X, verifique se tem algum elemento Y cujo `prev` ou `next` seja igual ao `id` de X (assim, você sabe se X deve vir antes ou depois de Y).

Uma alternativa - mais ineficiente, como veremos ao final - seria:

```js
function insertAt(array, pos, element, notsorted, alreadySorted) {
    if (!alreadySorted.has(element.id)) {
        array.splice(pos, 0, element);
        alreadySorted.add(element.id);
        notsorted.delete(element);
    }
}

// insere o elemento na posição correta
function insert(array, element, notsorted, alreadySorted) {
    // array vazio, simplesmente insere porque não tem outros elementos para comparar
    if (array.length == 0) {
        insertAt(array, 0, element, notsorted, alreadySorted);
        return;
    }

    if (element.id === element.prev) { // primeiro
        insertAt(array, 0, element, notsorted, alreadySorted);
    } else if (element.id === element.next) { // último
        insertAt(array, array.length, element, notsorted, alreadySorted);
    } else { // está no meio, tem que encontrar a posição
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            const current = array[i];
            if (current.next === element.id) { // elemento vai depois do atual
                insertAt(array, i + 1, element, notsorted, alreadySorted);
                break;
            } else if (current.prev === element.id) { // elemento vai antes do atual
                insertAt(array, i, element, notsorted, alreadySorted);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
    
var positions = [
  { name: 'Quinto', id: 2, prev: 3, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 3, prev: 1, next: 2 },
  { name: 'Sexto', id: 6, prev: 2, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 5, prev: 5, next: 7 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 1, prev: 7, next: 3 }
];

const sorted = [];
let notsorted = new Set(positions);
let alreadySorted = new Set();
do {
    for (const pos of notsorted) {
        insert(sorted, pos, notsorted, alreadySorted);
    }
} while(notsorted.size > 0);
console.log(sorted);

/*
[
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 5, prev: 5, next: 7 },
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 1, prev: 7, next: 3 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 3, prev: 1, next: 2 },
  { name: 'Quinto', id: 2, prev: 3, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Sexto', id: 6, prev: 2, next: 6 }
]
*/
```

Um detalhe chato é que, principalmente no início, não adianta fazer uma busca simples pelos elementos já ordenados, pois pode ser que o array `sorted` ainda não tenha o elemento que venha imediatamente antes ou depois do elemento a ser inserido. Com isso ele acaba ficando "perdido", então tenho que guardá-lo para tentar de novo posteriormente (quando `sorted` terá então mais elementos e a chance do antecessor ou sucessor estar lá aumenta). Isso faz com que este algoritmo seja bem ineficiente.

---

Tem outra forma mais simples e eficiente, adaptada [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44586196) (pois lá ele considera que há mais de um elemento que é o primeiro, então eu alterei para ter apenas um).

A ideia é criar um `Map` que mapeia cada elemento pelo seu id. Na construção deste `Map` aproveitamos para pegar o primeiro elemento.

Depois, fazemos um *loop* começando pelo primeiro elemento, e a partir dele buscamos o próximo no `Map`, até chegar no último:

```js
var positions = [
  { name: 'Quinto', id: 2, prev: 3, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 7, prev: 5, next: 1 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 3, prev: 1, next: 2 },
  { name: 'Sexto', id: 6, prev: 2, next: 6 },
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 5, prev: 5, next: 7 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 1, prev: 7, next: 3 }
];

const byId = new Map();
let first = null;
for (const pos of positions) {
    byId.set(pos.id, pos);
    if (pos.id === pos.prev)
        first = pos;
}
const sorted = [];
for (let x = first; x != null; x = byId.get(x.next)){
    sorted.push(x);
    if (x.next === x.id) // chegou no último, pode parar
        break;
}
console.log(sorted);
```

E claro, pode-se usar também um objeto simples em vez do `Map`:

```js
const byId = {};
let first = null;
for (const pos of positions) {
    byId[pos.id] = pos;
    if (pos.id === pos.prev)
        first = pos;
}
const sorted = [];
for (let x = first; x != null; x = byId[x.next]){
    sorted.push(x);
    if (x.next === x.id) // chegou no último, pode parar
        break;
}
```

---

Como curiosidade, fiz alguns testes com o [Benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/), tanto com o array acima quanto com casos maiores (1000 elementos, 100.000 elementos, etc). A primeira solução se mostrou lenta demais comparado com as outras. Já `Map` ficou cerca de 50% pior do que com um objeto simples para arrays grandes (mas para o caso acima, a diferença foi irrisória).

Answer (score 0):

Olá aparentemente é um de lógica, fiz da maneira abaixo e funcionou.

> Segue exemplo:

```
positions.sort(function (a,b) {
     if(a.prev <= b.prev && a.next <= b.next) {
             return -1;
     } else if(a.prev == b.prev && a.next == b.next) {
             return 0;
     } else {
             return 1;
     }
});
```

Comment: Não creio que isso seja válido, já que os ID's não influenciam diretamente nisso (digo influenciar no que diz respeito a um ser maior que o outro). Irei editar a resposta para deixar mais claro.

Comment: Tudo bem Luiz, fico no aguardo.

Comment: Editei lá! Se tiver ficado confuso pode avisar. Valeu!

Comment: Ainda não entendi pq o id 5 é o primeiro

Comment: Os dados (objetos) vêm de um banco de dados relacional. O `id` é um campo (primário) com auto-increment.

Comment: Vou remover a resposta amanhã penso em algo

Answer (score 0):

Não teria como comparar palavras, se uma é "maior ou menor" desta forma. Por exemplo, por ordem alfabética a palavra "Segundo" seria maior que "Quarto". Uma forma seria usar um objeto auxiliar onde cada palavra teria um valor numérico associado, ou seja, "Primeiro = 1", "Segundo = 2" e assim por diante.

Assim você consegue fazer as comparações pelo valor atribuído às palavras:

```js
const pos = {
   'Primeiro': 1,
   'Segundo': 2,
   'Terceiro': 3,
   'Quarto': 4
}

const positions = [
  { name: 'Segundo', id: 2, prev: 1, next: 3 },
  { name: 'Quarto', id: 4, prev: 3, next: 4 },
  { name: 'Primeiro', id: 1, prev: 1, next: 2 },
  { name: 'Terceiro', id: 3, prev: 2, next: 3 }
]

const sorted = positions.sort(function (a,b) {
   if(pos[a.name] > pos[b.name]) return 1;
});
console.log(sorted);
```